# Lose focus of button

Tags: c#, wpf, button, focus

There is a button which is clicked programmatically with code below but it stays as focused (I am not sure with terminology though). How can I get rid of that?

[image: after] [image: before]

```
private void txt_addRemove_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        btn_BC_add.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));                
    }
}
```

Comment: You provided two images. What are them for? Before and after raising the event? I think they can't be! And what is your desired outcome? Raise the event without focusing the button? Raising click events has nothing to do with focus change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart a fact that **really** wired to call a `ButtonClick`. What you *should* do, instead, at least define a `Command`, associate it to a button, and from this code **do not** call `RaiseEvent`, but call `Command` associated to that button. In practise you call a function.

What about a focus, *should* be enough to set esplicitly a focus to some other control on your view.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do what you want properly, here is one:

It's best to set the [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) to `PropertyChanged` and use a `Command` to bind the Enter key to. This should be the same command that you're Button binds to (so move your business logic to the view-model layer).

---

Alternatively, if this is the only Button on your form, you can set the `IsDefault` property to true (you'll still want to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`TraversalRequest Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.traversalrequest.aspx) to [`MoveFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.movefocus.aspx) or explicitly set your [`Focus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focus.aspx) to another element.

i.e.

```
btn_BC_add.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

---

Just in case that your button is last in the Focus order, you can try other [`FocusNavigationDirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusnavigationdirection.aspx) options such as Previous, First, Last, Left, Right, Up, Down, 
.

Comment: @Shibli  As MD.Unicorn said in his comment, the act of programically clicking does not set focus to your button. You need to determine where/what is setting the focus. Try adding a GotFocus event to your button and set a breakpoint. You can then use <ctrl>L to list your call stack to determine what is setting focus to your button.